# Pull to refresh throwing this error

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, refresh

I'm trying to implement pull to refresh in my cloud kit note app but I am getting the following error when I pull down to run refresh:

> 2016-01-24 12:36:01.078 ClipCloud2016Beta[13325:521249] -[ClipCloud2016Beta.MasterViewController HandleRefresh:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd77b4612f0
>   2016-01-24 12:36:01.084 ClipCloud2016Beta[13325:521249] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ClipCloud2016Beta.MasterViewController HandleRefresh:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd77b4612f0'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010db5ae65 **exceptionPreprocess + 165
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010f89adeb objc_exception_throw + 48
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010db6348d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
>       3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010dab090a ___forwarding_** + 970
>       4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010dab04b8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
>       5   UIKit                               0x000000010e379194 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
>       6   UIKit                               0x000000010e4e86fc -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
>       7   UIKit                               0x000000010e4e89c8 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 311
>       8   UIKit                               0x000000010ececc0b -[UIRefreshControl _setRefreshControlState:notify:] + 456
>       9   UIKit                               0x000000010ecf4ec3 **52-[_UIRefreshControlModernContentView _snappingMagic]_block_invoke + 57
>       10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110a8de5d _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
>       11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110aae49b _dispatch_client_callout + 8
>       12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110a93746 _dispatch_after_timer_callback + 334
>       13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110aae49b _dispatch_client_callout + 8
>       14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110aa18a5 _dispatch_source_latch_and_call + 1750
>       15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110a9c830 _dispatch_source_invoke + 1057
>       16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110a96111 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1324
>       17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010dabad09 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE** + 9
>       18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010da7c2c9 __CFRunLoopRun + 2073
>       19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010da7b828 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
>       20  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000111a38ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
>       21  UIKit                               0x000000010e377610 UIApplicationMain + 171
>       22  ClipCloud2016Beta                   0x000000010d81925d main + 109
>       23  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000110ae292d start + 1
>       24  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
>   )
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
>   (lldb)

I have enabled Refresh in storyboard of UITableview

Implemented the following in `ViewDidLoad()`

```
 self.refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: "HandleRefresh:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
```

This is my refresh method:

```
    func handleRefresh(refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {


    self.tableView.reloadData()
    refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```

It's worth nothing that the line   `self.tableView.reloadData()` works elsewhere in my code.

Might also be worth nothing that when error occurs Xcode ends up in my AppDelegate class at this line

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UISplitViewControllerDelegate {
```

Comment: `HandleRefresh` vs `handleRefresh` - one timer upper case first letter, one time lower case first letter.

Comment: Thanks @luk2302, if you feel up to it I have another question I am stuck on in my profile :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue solved by commenter

HandleRefresh vs handleRefresh spelling error between method and call.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed mine :

```
refreshControl.addTarget(self, action:
        #selector(ViewController.HandleRefresh(sender:)),
                             for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
```